# WebSocket connection to 'wss://url' failed: Unknown reason

Tags: websocket

the WebSocket connection is some time.

WebSocket connection to 'localhost:8002/WebDav/doc1.docx' failed: Unknown reason

not getting what is the Unknown reason. please advise any solution to this.

code -

```
var socket = new WebSocket("wss://url"); 
socket.addEventListener('message', function (e) 
{
  var notifyObject = JSON.parse(e.data); // Checking message type after receiving. 
  if(notifyObject.EventType === "refresh") { } 
}, false)
```

Comment: Your code suggests a new connection is made to `wss://url` but the error is on `localhost:8002/WebDav/doc1.docx` can you explain what is that url a typo or literal string "url"

Comment: its wss://localhost:8002/WebDav/doc1.docx

Comment: How are you configuring the server ?